# Jquery not working if div id have $

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing issue with my jquery .my div id is $divid. if iam removing $ from my div  id then it works fine.below is my code.You can also check it on fiddler.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ewdge/34/

```
<div id="$divid">

    <span>a</span>

    <span>b</span>

    <span>c</span> 

</div>    

<div id="divid2">

    <span>e</span>

    <span>f</span>

    <span>g</span>

 </div>

var itemu = $('#$divid span');

for (var i = 0; i <= itemu.length; i++) {

HTML = itemu[i].innerHTML;

alert(HTML);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help you solving your problem, but you should avoid using 'weird' characters like $, @, & in your element's ID. With alphanumeric characters and dashes you have more then enough (endless to be exact) combinations of ID's

Answer (score 2):

You should escape `$`:

```
$('#\\$divid span');
```

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
> `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ewdge/37/

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `$` with `\\`

```
var itemu = $('#\\$divid span');
```

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

[Doc reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

escape $ in id.like this:

```
 var itemu = $('#\\$divid span');
for (var i = 0; i <= itemu.length; i++) {
 HTML = itemu[i].innerHTML;
 alert(HTML);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ewdge/35/)**

or use:

```
ID="$divid";
var itemu =$('[id=ID]')
```

Answer (score -1):

The `id` name cannot begin with `$`. It must begin with a `_`, `-`, or letter.

Comment: I stand "technically" corrected as I can't locate CSS3 docs preventing this. However, I would strongly recommend against using symbols to prevent the need to escape CSS selectors. I can see no benefit in keeping them.